# Session is not set after redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I've created a project in Codeigniter. My problem is when I log in, auth controller shows the value that is set in session $this->session->userdata("logged_in") but it is not redirecting to dashboard.

I also changed the PHP version on the live server from `PHP 7.1` to `PHP 5.6` but it's still not working. Session works perfectly on local server with xampp but not working on live server

**Auth_model**

```
  public function Authentification() {
    $notif = array();
    $email = $this->input->post('email',TRUE);
    $password = Utils::hash('sha1', $this->input->post('password'), AUTH_SALT);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $row = $query->row();
        if ($row->is_active != 1) {
            $notif['message'] = 'Your account is disabled !';
            $notif['type'] = 'warning';
        } else {
            $sess_data = array(
                'users_id' => $row->users_id,
                'first_name' => $row->first_name,
                'email' => $row->email
            );
           $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_data);

        }
    } else {
        $notif['message'] = 'Username or password incorrect !';
        $notif['type'] = 'danger';
    }

    return $notif;
}
```

**Auth controller**

```
 class Auth extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    Utils::no_cache();
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
        exit;
    }
}



public function index() {
        redirect(base_url('home'));
    }

 public function login() {
    $data['title'] = 'Login';
    $this->load->model('auth_model');

    if (count($_POST)) {
        $this->load->helper('security');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email address', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            // $data['notif']['message'] = validation_errors();
            // $data['notif']['type'] = 'danger';
              $status = validation_errors();
             if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
                echo json_encode($status);
                exit;
            }
        } 
        else {
            $data['notif'] = $this->auth_model->Authentification();
                  //  it show the result here but not redirect to dashboard
             //    print_r($this->session->userdata("logged_in"));
        //         die("auth/login");
        }
    }


    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
        exit;
    }

    /*
     * Load view
     */
    $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('home/index');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

**dashboard**

```
  class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

var $session_user;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('auth_model');
     $this->load->helper('tool_helper');

    Utils::no_cache();
    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect(base_url('home'));
        exit;
    }
    $this->session_user = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

}

/*
 * 
 */

public function index() {
    $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';
    $data['session_user'] = $this->session_user;
    // print_r($this->session->userdata("logged_in")); //its show empty
    $data['items'] = $this->auth_model->get_all_products();

    $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
    // $this->load->view('includes/navbar');
    $this->load->view('includes/navbar_new');
    $this->load->view('dashboard/index');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

I don't know why session not set. I have been stuck in this for a week. Please help me out.

Comment: What it show instead of redirect in page? If It have create session than you can see session cookies. If no session cookies mean problem are in session creation else problem in dashboard link

Comment: What's the session setting in your /application/config.php file? Are you seeing any error messages in the log file?

Comment: And If session library is not autoload, than load it by `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: If sessions work on local but not on live server then you need to make certain that Session and Cookie variables (in config.php) are appropriate for the live server.

Comment: Do you have error logging enabled on live server? Local vs live problems are always hard to diagnose without the proper information

Comment: yes error log enable but no error show on this @Alex

Comment: @Artier  this is my session setting $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

Comment: i also upload another ci project on my  server but same problem session empty

Comment: Check this line in config>autoload.php , Exists or not?` $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');`

Comment: Session exists in autoload['libraries]

Comment: Change `$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();` to `$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/sessions/';` in config.php

Comment: Session  working thanku so much @Artier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Change `$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();` to `$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/sessions/';` in config.php